# Отобразить src для каждого изображения

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Проблема заключается в том, что при клике на каждое изображение из слайдера, должен выводиться его src. Вместо этого всегда выводиться src одного из них.

```
<ul>
    <li><img class="img" width="350" src="http://static.pyimagesearch.com.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vacation-photos/queries/103100.png"></li>
    <li><img class="img" width="350" src="http://static.pyimagesearch.com.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vacation-photos/queries/103300.png"></li>
    <li><img class="img" width="350" src="http://static.pyimagesearch.com.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vacation-photos/queries/127502.png"></li>
    <li><img class="img" width="350" src="http://static.pyimagesearch.com.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vacation-photos/queries/123600.png"></li>
</ul>
```

Код обработчика нажатия

```
$('li').click(function(event) {  
    var imgsrc = $('img', this).attr('src');  
    alert(imgsrc);
    $(this).addClass("active");
    if (imgsrc!='') {
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "/showDiagram", 
        data: { img : imgsrc},          
        success:function(res){
          $("#res").html(res);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#res").html("");
    }                
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
addEventListener(`click`, e => {
  if (e.target.tagName != `IMG`) return;
  console.log(e.target.src);
});
```

```css
img {
  border: 2px dashed purple;
  min-height: 20px;
  min-width: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img class="img" width="350" src="http://static.pyimagesearch.com.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vacation-photos/queries/103100.png"></li>
  <li><img class="img" width="350" src="http://static.pyimagesearch.com.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vacation-photos/queries/103300.png"></li>
  <li><img class="img" width="350" src="http://static.pyimagesearch.com.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vacation-photos/queries/127502.png"></li>
  <li><img class="img" width="350" src="http://static.pyimagesearch.com.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vacation-photos/queries/123600.png"></li>
</ul>
```